# Grpc integration with spring camel web app

Tags: grpc, spring-camel

I have a web service built on spring-camel. I am trying to integrate the grpc server using [grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter). My implementation of grpc service is as below.

```
@GrpcService
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void processGrpcRequest(GreetingRequest request, StreamObserver<GreetingResponse> responseObserver) {

        String receivedMessage = request.getRequest();

        GreetingResponse response = GreetingResponse.newBuilder()
                .setResponse("Your message received " + receivedMessage).build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

}
```

I package my web service as a war and I find no error during deployement of the war file in my application server. However, when I try to communicate with my grpc server, I get the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" 15:18:01.363 [grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler - [id: 0x02a01ffb, L:/127.0.0.1:56000 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9089] INBOUND PING: ack=true bytes=1234
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: HTTP status code 404
invalid content-type: text/html
headers: Metadata(:status=404,content-type=text/html,date=Fri, 04 Mar 2022 09:48:01 GMT,content-length=74)
DATA-----------------------------
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.test.grpc.GreetingServiceGrpc$GreetingServiceBlockingStub.processGrpcRequest(GreetingServiceGrpc.java:156)
    at com.test.grpc.GrpcClient.main(GrpcClient.java:16)
```

I have recreated the same issue with minimal setup and code is available here [github](https://github.com/balanmoorthi/grpc-issue) . Please can anyone help on this. Thanks

Comment: The `@GrpcService` require spring boot. Your project is a spring boot project, so it can't init grpc service when startup. You need register grpc service manual to grpc server.

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out. but can you share more on how to register grpc service as manual.

Comment: Register to server like: `Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new InetSocketAddress(9090).addService(new GreetingServiceImpl()).build();` And then start the server by `server.start()`; For more detail, you can reference this project: [https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample](https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample/blob/main/helloworld/src/main/java/io/github/helloworlde/grpc/HelloWorldServer.java)